# is there an ubuntu minimal or core server iso NOT containing anything snapware related?

Tags: server, snap, iso

I sofar have had to manually uninstall everything snapware related and in some cases snaps already started to prohibit my system from booting before I even touched anything. Something I haven't ever encountered in my past 15 years among the Tuxs.

Also manual uninstall always comes with the risk to permanently damage the installation.

I want a clean repo fed library on my server installation and I would hate to be forced to switch distribution for my servers just to be able to ge that without the current hassle.

**It is a thing of principles so please spare the questions why I won't accept it:**

1. It does not honour the Linux way of things.
2. library bloated software does encourage qualitativly subpar coding.

I do honour the work Devs and volunteers put In to the Snap project even tho I wished they would not try to introduce this concept we already seen going havoc in the NT-World into the Linux user environment. But this is only my opinion alone and there might be good reasons for this from someone else's PoV.

Comment: Why not Debian? The installer is more complex, but you can still use a DE (GNOME, KDE, xfce4, and more are supported as presets), and it doesn't include Snap. Ubuntu is based on Debian, so it isn't that different.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to look at a different distro. In the server space, Ubuntu really doesn’t offer much of any advantage other than familiarity (they have essentially nothing ‘new’, and most third-party software for Linux servers targets a number of distros, not just Ubuntu like seems to be the unfortunate norm for desktop stuff). Alpine would be my suggestion if you can tolerate learning something new and don’t need any proprietary software, otherwise Debian or possibly Fedora is likely to be the best fit.

Comment: This will very likely be the case if I can not find any Ubuntu alternatives which do what I am searching for. I have had my fair share of Debian experience so that will likely be what I will use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focussing on the crux of the issue ...

**Q. Is there an ubuntu minimal or core server iso NOT containing anything snapware related?**

Yes. Ubuntu Server versions 4.10 ~ 15.10. That said, none of these releases are supported anymore<sup>1</sup>.

If the goal is to have a supported and updatable installation of Ubuntu, then one option that you might consider would be to create your own distribution with a tool like [Linux Live Kit](https://www.linux-live.org) or [Ubuntu Imager](https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager). This will allow you to configure an installation to suit your exact needs.

---

1. Extended Security Maintenance was available for Ubuntu 14.04 [until earlier this month](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-14-04-esm-support).

Comment: Or use a distribution other than Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for that slightly trollish answer and as could be assumed I am indeed looking for a supported version. If that is not available Ubuntu sadly is about to be history to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Cubic](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic) to customize the ISO and remove `snapd` all together.

1. Install Cubic.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install --no-install-recommends cubic
   ```
2. Select your the `*.iso` you would like to customize.
3. In the Cubic terminal, execute `apt purge snapd`.
4. Click through the GUI to generate the final ISO without snap.

(Note that `snap` commands such as `snap list`, `snap remove`, etc. won't work in [Cubic's Terminal](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Terminal-Page), but all you really need is the `apt purge snap` command).

Comment: I will give this a try, thank you :)

Comment: @Seemax Did you give this a try? Any results to share? I'm curious as someone who's been using Ubuntu as my daily driver for over a decade, the inherent delays in using snaps are ticking me off as well.

Comment: I suggest using the [ISO with the legacy installer (i.e. Ubiquity)](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/mantic/release/ubuntu-23.10-desktop-legacy-amd64.iso) since it works best with Cubic.